# How to get input range during change

Tags: javascript, html, input, return-value

I need to get values to my script on pyscript.
I can send values but I do not view live changes, with this code y can see the live changes and control the value by change event.[image]

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is add an `onChange` listener to the input which runs a function every time the value is updated. You can then access the new values and use them where needed.

Answer (score -3):

I solve my problem with this code
Note: It does not replace the value of the input range value
you can use 'onchange="changeFunction()"' for get value input or how you need to get value

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h3>How to view range change value.</h3>
  <input type="range" id="myrange" value="50" min="0" max="500" oninput="document.getElementById('outputVal').innerHTML = this.value" />
  <label id="outputVal"></label>
</body>

</html>
```

My References
[Demo](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/practice-ground/default.htm?pg=html5_oninput_attribute_example)
[Doc](https://www.encodedna.com/html5/howto-read-values-from-html5-input-type-range-using-javascript.htm)